# Does this count as an acceptable adsense implementation?

Tags: html, google-adsense, layout, advertising

After being disgusted with mostly $0 RPM on my mobile site, I thought of a new idea but I'm not sure if it will be acceptable.

On Google's own help pages, I noticed on the responsive section they load the script after the insertion tag, and on other pages, they load it before the script tag. For example:

```
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="6440411535"></ins>
 <script>
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
 </script>
```

and

```
 <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="6440411535"></ins>
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
 <script>
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
 </script>
```

I'm just curious as to an implementation where the script file loads before HTML content is loaded but the ad loads after text appears on the screen is acceptable.

For example, Consider this HTML:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>bla</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
  <!--

  ALL HTML code of my site before ad unit

  -->
  <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
     data-ad-slot="6440411535"></ins>
 <script>
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
 </script>
  <!--

  ALL HTML code of my site after ad unit

  -->
  </body>
  </html>
```

I was also thinking of loading the script within the HEAD tags but I think that would force the script to load in synchronous mode, I'm not sure.

So my question is, is my idea acceptable to adsense, or do they expect all their tags to be together regardless of the order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure could we consider that as a "modification", but in my understanding it is acceptable - AdSense Help Center says `adsbygoogle.js` can be loaded once, and it doesn't say where.

`adsbygoogle.js` within the `HEAD` tags is loaded asynchronously - the `async` attribute if forcing asynchronous mode.

About the asynchronous ad code > FAQ
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3221666

http://googledevelopers.blogspot.rs/2013/07/an-async-script-for-adsense-tagging.html

Adding only a single adsense script in sites
https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/adsense/HFRhmEhpNrI/IMaTUe9VzUAJ

(Btw. - maybe you could [respond to comments and suggestions](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/88863/would-a-cdn-solve-the-problem-of-me-making-0-rpm-on-my-mobile-site) if you want help with $0RPM?)